# How do I set a specific set of print instructions to the instances of my class?

Tags: python, class, object, printing

I was hoping to set specific instructions for the printing of the instance of my class. For example, I have the class `food` (with details such as *price, rating,* and *customer_preference*, with an object `lobster` and `chicken`. Both objects have different details, what I was hoping to do is that, when I call an object to print, it would print details unique to itself. How do I do that? I can't seem to put the right words to find the answer by simply searching so I thought I could ask here.

Answer (score 1):

The whole idea of Object-Oriented Programming is that the class defines the basic behaviour of a specific group of related objects. The specific behaviour of individual instance of a class is often achieved by passing different attributes when initialising an instance.

Here you need to define these variables as class attributes in the `__init__` constructor and then provide different values when you create instances for different products:

```py
class Food:

   def __init__(self, name: str, price: float, rating: int, customer_preference):
       self.name = name
       self.price = price
       self.rating = rating
       self.customer_preference = customer_preference

   def print_info(self):
       print(f'{self.name.capitalize()} costs ${self.price} and has a rating of {self.rating}.')


chicken = Food('chicken', 12.50, 85, None)
chicken.print_info()
```

This will output:

`Chicken costs $12.50 and has a rating of 85.`

Not sure how you plan to use `customer_preference` attribute so I passed `None` as the value to the constructor.

**EDIT:**
We can also use `@classmethod` decorator to return a specific instance of a class based simply on a name of product:

```
class Food:
    mapper = {'chicken' : {'price' : 12.50, 'rating' : 85, 'customer preference': None},
        'okra' : {'price' : 8.40, 'rating' : 70, 'customer preference' : 'vegetarian'}}
    
    def __init__(self, name: str, price: float, rating: int, customer_preference: str):

       self.name = name
       self.price = price
       self.rating = rating
       self.customer_preference = customer_preference
    
    @classmethod
    def from_name(cls, name: str, mapper=mapper):
        price = mapper[name]['price']
        rating = mapper[name]['rating']
        customer_preference = mapper[name]['customer preference']
        
        return cls(name, price, rating, customer_preference)
    
    def print_stuff(self):
        if self.customer_preference:
            print(f'{self.name.capitalize()} costs ${self.price}, has a rating of {self.rating} and is suitable for {self.customer_preference} diet.')
            
        else:
            print(f'{self.name.capitalize()} costs ${self.price} and has a rating of {self.rating}.')
            
okra = Food.from_name('okra')
okra.print_stuff()
```

This outputs:

`Okra costs $8.4, has a rating of 70 and is suitable for vegetarian diet.`

Comment: Perhaps emphasize that the whole *point* of object-oriented programming is that the class defines a general behavior and individual instances contain parameters for that behavior in that instance, typically by way of instance attributes.

Comment: I was actually rooting for a method that uses this, ```print(chicken)```, that result similarly, that is also built-in in the class method. However, this is a well-appreciated and good alternative for me. Thanks.

Comment: @MhonnYbañez, see updated answer for the version with a `@classmethod`.